# Changing Android Device to Accessory Mode

Tags: android, linux, usb

I'm trying to get my android device (nexus 7) and linux machine to communicate with each other through an usb cable. I'm using the USBDeviceConnection, USBDevice, USBAccessory classes. When I run the app, it does not pickup the linux machine. So I was wondering if I needed to change my android device into USBAccessory mode and how would i do that. Or if there was some other way to have the app on my android device pickup up my linux machine through usb and send data to it.